# Linq Query Join Tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I have this Linq Query I run a search function on (DateFrom and DateTo are dateTime objects):

```
 var result = from x in DbContext.Transaction_Groups
 where  (x.Date_Created >= DateFrom && x.Date_Created <= DateTo)
 select x;
```

And these are my tables:

[image]

I'm trying to join these two tables together so that I can use the `.Transaction_Date_Time` instead of the `.Date_Created function` that's in my query.

My query is trying to determine all the rows between the `DateFrom` (user selected value) and the `DateTo` (Another user selected value).

Comment: [Join Examples Linq](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to join by Group_ID?

```
 var result = from x in DbContext.Transaction_Groups
 join tran in DbContext.CashDeposit on x.Group_ID equals tran.Group_ID
 where  (tran.Transaction_Date_Time >= DateFrom && tran.Transaction_Date_Time <= DateTo)
 select tran;
```

Comment: I really find it weird to give the variable of one table a name that is the start of the other table. In fact, it's confusing, just like using single letter variables is.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from transgroup in DbContext.Transaction_Groups
             join cashDep in DbContext.CashDeposit
             on transgroup.Group_ID equals cashDep.Group_ID
             where (cashDep.Transaction_Date_Time >= DateFrom
                    && cashDep.Transaction_Date_Time <= DateTo)
             select transgroup
```

Untested, but should work. indentation for clarity.